# Javascript PUT request without using ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send a put request to our server, however, the server does not allow an ajax function because it does not think that it is authorized to talk to the server. I am wondering if there are other ways to send a put request that don't use the ajax function.

Comment: The server has no idea how you did the request. Maybe you just need to authenticate somehow?

Comment: The real question here is is that is you server set up like that? Maybe you should address that instead.

Comment: You are here speaking in term of server but in reality it seems that most browsers don't support other methods besides GET and POST

Comment: We have done a request in postman, and have seen that our server can take PUT requests. We cannot change how the server works, this is for a hackathon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible situation is that you are being blocked by the browser for trying to make a cross-domain request.
This means: the document (html file) is being loaded from `<protocol, hostname, port>` combination 1, but you are trying to make an ajax request to `<protocol, hostname, port>` combination 2.

If this is the case, and this is a hackaton - you can just disable the same-origin policy checks in your browser, [such as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome).

For more accurate answer, you should probably provide more details about the error you are getting.